# Why does the top of a float div not align with the parent div?

Tags: css, html, css-float

I'm trying to create a section of a page where two text divs align with each other, but one floats to the right of the other. Whatever I try, the floating div seems to leave about one blank line of text before it starts.

Fiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/7MpYj/

Here's what it looks like in Chrome (and Safari):

[image]

I've played with margin, padding, vertical-align, and nothing seems to get rid of the blank line between the two.

CSS is:

```
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 13px;
}
div.sidebar {
  width: 300px;
  float: right;
  background: pink;
}
div.maincolumn {
  background: #aaffaa;
}
div.clear {
  clear: right;
}
```

HTML is:

```
<div class="maincolumn">
  <div class="sidebar">
    <h3>Constitution</h3>
    We the People of the United States, in Order to form a more perfect
    Union, establish Justice, insure domestic Tranquility, provide for
    the common defence, promote the general Welfare, and secure the
    Blessings of Liberty to ourselves and our Posterity, do ordain and
    establish this Constitution for the United States of America.
  </div>
  <h3>Declaration</h3>
  When in the Course of human events, it becomes necessary for one
  people to dissolve the political bands which have connected them with
  another, and to assume among the powers of the earth, the separate and
  equal station to which the Laws of Nature and of Nature's God entitle
  them, a decent respect to the opinions of mankind requires that they
  should declare the causes which impel them to the separation.
  <p/>
  We hold these truths to be self-evident, that all men are created
  equal, that they are endowed by their Creator with certain unalienable
  Rights, that among these are Life, Liberty and the pursuit of
  Happiness.--That to secure these rights, Governments are instituted
  among Men, deriving their just powers from the consent of the
  governed, --That whenever any Form of Government becomes destructive
  of these ends, it is the Right of the People to alter or to abolish
  it, and to institute new Government, laying its foundation on such
  principles and organizing its powers in such form, as to them shall
  seem most likely to effect their Safety and Happiness.
</div>
<div class="clear">
  Edward by the grace of God King of England, lord of Ireland and
  duke of Aquitaine sends greetings to all to whom the present
  letters come. We have inspected the great charter of the lord
  Henry, late King of England, our father, concerning the liberties
  of England in these words:
</div>
```

Is there some CSS magic which will pull up the text in the floating div?

Comment: I don't really understand what you mean -- could you be more specific about what you want it to look like?

Comment: I'd like the words "Declaration" and "Constitution" to be aligned, ideally at the top of the containing colored boxes. Is that clearer?

Comment: got it. i just posted an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. Add `overflow:auto` to `div.maincolumn`

```
div.maincolumn {
    background: #aaffaa;
    overflow:auto;
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/7MpYj/1/)**

Your particular layout is an example of [block formatting context](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Block_formatting_context) and how `overflow:auto` can restore the behavior you seek.

Comment: Thanks. That works, but it does so by pushing down the left (non-floating) text rather than raising the right (floating) text. But I'm off to read about block formatting context.

Comment: @ShouldKnowThisAlready expand the view of your jsfiddle. it allready works as you want to. try it again.

Comment: What you're seeing is the normal margin on an h3 element. If you remove it via CSS you can get what I think you want: http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/7MpYj/4/

Comment: Yes, thanks. Your explanation plus @Vijay's above together explain that. I hadn't understand that the margin was disappearing in the main column.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your css:

```
div.sidebar h3 {
    margin-top:0;
}
```

Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7MpYj/3/

Comment: Doh! Thanks – it hadn't occurred to me that the issue was the h3, rather than the floating. Now I understand the answer by @j08691, where the block formatting context meant that both the main and floating columns showed the h3's margin.

Answer (score 0):

Try to adjust the vertical alignment to pull the text the top:

```
div.sidebar {
    vertical-align: top;
}
```